# How can I automate the addition from WorkbookConnections with VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I want to connect csv files with excels power pivot with a VBA code by using WorkbookConnection.AddfromFile

My question:

I want to connect numerous csv file. To do so I have to click for hours through the Text Import Wizard. I haven't found out yet how to automatize this! I imagine to do it in a similar way like I did it with the FileDialog in the upper part of my code. Below the part of my code where I want to implement it.

```
For LoopCounter = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.count
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections.AddFromFile _
        fd.SelectedItems(LoopCounter), True, False
Next LoopCounter
```

Below the code I have already written. With this code I have to click through the TextImportWizard manually.

```
Sub csv()

Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim ActionClicked As Boolean
Dim LoopCounter As Long

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

fd.InitialFileName = "C:\temp"
fd.AllowMultiSelect = True
fd.Title = "Open your data"
fd.ButtonName = "GO"

ActionClicked = fd.Show

If ActionClicked Then

    For LoopCounter = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.count

        ActiveWorkbook.Connections.AddFromFile _
        fd.SelectedItems(LoopCounter), True, False

    Next LoopCounter

Else

    MsgBox "You didn't choose anything"
    Exit Sub

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The faster way to import CSV or text files is with the following

```
Dim InputStringCSV As String
Dim CSVFile As Variant
Dim ArrayStringCSV() As String
CSVFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV Files,*.CSV", Title:="MyData")
 If CSVFile = False Then "No input!", vbCritical: End
 Open CSVFile For Input As #1
  Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, InputStringCSV
        ArrayStringCSV = Split(InputStringCSV, Chr(10))
        For CounterArray = LBound(ArrayStringCSV) To UBound(ArrayStringCSV)
        'Defaults: Row 1 is the beginnning for the sheet
            Sheets(Sheet_CSV).Cells(1 + CounterArray, 1).NumberFormat = "@"
            Sheets(Sheet_CSV).Cells(1 + CounterArray, 1) = ArrayStringCSV(CounterArray)
        Next CounterArray
    Loop
    Close #1
```

If you want to automate it for all the CSV files in a folder, I'd suggest that you loop through archives -looking for .csv ones-, here's a sample on how to get you started:

```
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
oStartFolder = "C:/Documents"
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(oStartFolder)
oFSO.GetFolder (oFolder)
For Each FileItem In oFolder.Files
if Instr(FileItem,".csv") Then Call ImportCSV(FileName) 'you would change the above code to don't ask folder and set the argument so each time you call it would be the file csv in the folder
Next FileItem
```

Comment: PowerPivot: Thx for your answer. But that is not exactly what I want. I'm using the PowerPivot AddIn. With ActiveWorkbook.Connections.AddFromFile I can add files to the "data model". For further processing I need these data in the datamodel...

Comment: The first code it's the "wizard" thingy simplified.

Comment: I'm quite new with VBA. Might be that I simply not understand you right. But I'm, after a lot of try and error, not able to implement the "wizard stuff" into the ActiveWork.Connections.AddFromFile stuff... Do you have some suggestions?

Comment: I think this is more complicated than I originally thought, the only documentatiton that may resemeble your case [is found here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx)

Comment: hmm couldn't find any way to solve this. But thx for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to import text files.  See the link below.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win022.htm

This AddIn will do the work for you.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm

Also, you can merge all your text files in a folder into one worksheet.

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" _
        (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, _
        ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, _
        ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" _
        (ByVal hProcess As Long, _
        lpExitCode As Long) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" _
        (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, _
        ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, _
        ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long

    Private Declare Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" _
        (ByVal hProcess As Long, _
        lpExitCode As Long) As Long
#End If


Public Const PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = &H400
Public Const STILL_ACTIVE = &H103


Public Sub ShellAndWait(ByVal PathName As String, Optional WindowState)
    Dim hProg As Long
    Dim hProcess As Long, ExitCode As Long
    'fill in the missing parameter and execute the program
    If IsMissing(WindowState) Then WindowState = 1
    hProg = Shell(PathName, WindowState)
    'hProg is a "process ID under Win32. To get the process handle:
    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, False, hProg)
    Do
        'populate Exitcode variable
        GetExitCodeProcess hProcess, ExitCode
        DoEvents
    Loop While ExitCode = STILL_ACTIVE
End Sub


Sub Merge_CSV_Files()
    Dim BatFileName As String
    Dim TXTFileName As String
    Dim XLSFileName As String
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim DefPath As String
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim oFolder
    Dim foldername

    'Create two temporary file names
    BatFileName = Environ("Temp") & _
            "\CollectCSVData" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy-h-mm-ss") & ".bat"
    TXTFileName = Environ("Temp") & _
            "\AllCSV" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy-h-mm-ss") & ".txt"

    'Folder where you want to save the Excel file
    DefPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
    If Right(DefPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        DefPath = DefPath & "\"
    End If

    'Set the extension and file format
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        'You use Excel 97-2003
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        'You use Excel 2007 or higher
        FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
        'If you want to save as xls(97-2003 format) in 2007 use
        'FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
    End If

    'Name of the Excel file with a date/time stamp
    XLSFileName = DefPath & "MasterCSV " & _
                  Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yyyy h-mm-ss") & FileExtStr

    'Browse to the folder with CSV files
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set oFolder = oApp.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select folder with CSV files", 512)
    If Not oFolder Is Nothing Then
        foldername = oFolder.Self.Path
        If Right(foldername, 1) <> "\" Then
            foldername = foldername & "\"
        End If

        'Create the bat file
        Open BatFileName For Output As #1
        Print #1, "Copy " & Chr(34) & foldername & "*.csv" _
                & Chr(34) & " " & TXTFileName
        Close #1

        'Run the Bat file to collect all data from the CSV files into a TXT file
        ShellAndWait BatFileName, 0
        If Dir(TXTFileName) = "" Then
            MsgBox "There are no csv files in this folder"
            Kill BatFileName
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Open the TXT file in Excel
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=TXTFileName, Origin:=xlWindows, StartRow _
                :=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
                ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, _
                Space:=False, Other:=False

        'Save text file as a Excel file
        Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Wb.SaveAs Filename:=XLSFileName, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        Wb.Close savechanges:=False
        MsgBox "You find the Excel file here: " & vbNewLine & XLSFileName

        'Delete the bat and text file you temporary used
        Kill BatFileName
        Kill TXTFileName

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

You'll find more info here.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win021.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the data connections, like I do, then you need to first make a query using Power Query M formula. Then you can add your connection to that query. This is what Excel does when you use the `Get Data` wizards.

Use this procedure in your loop and it will make a new sheet for each CSV file:

```
'@Description("Create a new worksheet with a table that is connected to a CSV file as a data source.")
Public Sub GetDataFromCSV(ByVal name As String, ByVal fileName As String)

    On Error GoTo errorHandler
    
    ' The Power Query points to the CSV file, if your data contains headers you need the Promoted Headers
    Dim csvFormula As String
    csvFormula = "let" & vbNewLine & _
                 "   Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""" & fileName & """),null,null,null,1252)," & vbNewLine & _
                 "   #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true])" & vbNewLine & _
                 "in" & vbNewLine & _
                 "   #""Promoted Headers"""
    
    ThisWorkbook.Queries.Add name:=name, Formula:=csvFormula
    
    ' The workbook connects to that query
    Dim newConnection As WorkbookConnection
    Set newConnection = ThisWorkbook.Connections.Add2("Query - " & name, _
        "Connection to the '" & name & "' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & name & ";Extended Properties="""";", """" & name & """", 6, True, False)
    
    ' I always want one table per sheet that begins at A1
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    Set newSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
    newSheet.name = name
    
    ' Only once you have the connection backed by the query can you link it to a Table
    With newSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcModel, Source:=newConnection, LinkSource:=True, XlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes, Destination:=newSheet.Range("$A$1")).TableObject
        .RowNumbers = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshStyle = 1
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        ' I get errors when there are hyphens in the DisplayName, the default behavior of the wizard replaces them with underscors
        .ListObject.DisplayName = Replace(name, "-", "_")
        .Refresh
    End With

    Exit Sub
    
errorHandler:
    If Err.Number = -2147024809 Then
        ' Query already exists, we delete it so we can recreate it
        ThisWorkbook.Queries.Item(name).Delete
        Resume
    Else
        Debug.Print "ERROR " & Err.Number & " : " & Err.Description
    End If
End Sub
```